# Cual es el sentido de hacer una cabecera.h en c?

Tags: c++, c, bash, gcc

Cual es la diferencia de incluir el archivo.c directamente que tener que hacer una libreria archivo.h e incluirla?

```
//1.c
int sumar(int a, int b)
{
    return a + b;
}
//2.c 
#include <stdio.h>
#include "1.c"

int main()
{
    int a = 5;
    int b = 61;
    int suma = sumar(a, b);
    printf("%d\n", suma);
    return 0;
}
```

Porque esto me funciona de igual forma que tener que hacer una cabecera 1.h

Comment: Porque puedes tener múltiples declaraciones para una misma función, pero solo una definición. Digamos que tienes un .c con una función `sumar`. Si necesitas usarla en otros 2 archivos tendrás símbolos duplicados, porque los dos .c tendrán una definición para la misma función.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para entender la necesidad de las cabeceras hay que entender cómo se compilan los programas en C.

El proceso de generación de código binario se divide en 3 etapas:

- precompilador
- compilación
- enlazado

En la fase del precompilador se reemplazan las macros y por el código fuente correspondiente. Durante esta fase, por ejemplo, se reemplazan los `#include` por el contenido del archivo al que hacen referencia

En la fase de compilación se coge cada archivo de código y se genera código objeto. El código objeto es una suerte de código binario incompleto. No hay saltos entre funciones que se encuentren en diferentes archivos, por ejemplo.

La fase final, el enlazado, coge todos los archivos de código objeto y los fusiona para generar el binario final.

Pues bien, durante la fase de compilación, el compilador necesita conocer la interfaz de los distintos objetos y funciones para poder hacer su trabajo correctamente. Esta fase no necesita conocer los detalles de dichos objetos y funciones (su implementación), solo necesita conocer su aspecto exterior.

Esto quiere decir que el compilador únicamente necesita saber qué forma tiene una función externa, le da absolutamente igual su implementación. Esta es la información que viaja en las cabeceras.

Pero ¿Y por qué no se fusionan las cabeceras y los archivos de código en un único fichero?

Por varias razones:

- Separar el código en dos permite que las cabeceras sean más pequeñas, lo que reduce la cantidad de información que tiene que procesar el compilador. Esto se traduce en compilaciones más rápidas y menor consumo de memoria.
- Usar cabeceras permite reducir el acoplamiento. Las cabeceras, al no tener código, pueden prescindir de dependencias que sí tienen que estar presentes en el archivo de código. Menos dependencias implica menos carga para el compilador y esto supone tiempos de compilación menores y menor consumo de memoria.
- Durante el proceso de enlazado existe una etapa de optimización que elimina el código duplicado. Si el código de una función se compila solo una vez, evitarás que el binario correspondiente esté duplicado varias veces, por lo que el enlazador tardará menos tiempo en hacer su trabajo.
- más razones que no expongo para no alargar demasiado la respuesta

El caso, como ves, todo va encaminado a reducir el tiempo y el consumo de memoria. Esto puede parecer un poco absurdo hoy en día que tenemos máquinas con 32 GB de memoria ... o más. Pero piensa que C/C++ son lenguajes de la década de los 70 y en esa época los equipos que estaban disponibles estaban tremendamente limitados. Piensa que los equipos tenían menos de 1MB de RAM y ya no hablamos de la rapidez de las CPUs.

Por resumir:

C y C++ son lenguajes que se diseñaron hace ya 50 años bajo las premisas de la época. Ello marcó su evolución hasta la actualidad.

Dividir el código en cabecera y código fue la forma que en ese momento se les ocurrió para permitir que las máquinas de entonces pudiesen hacer su trabajo de forma efectiva.

Comment: Entiendo, Muchas gracias por tomarte el tiempo de explicarme todo